# error in php crypt

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

i use such f-n to encrypt\decrypt

```
<?
//Encrypt Function
function mc_encrypt($encrypt, $mc_key) {
     $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
    $passcrypt = trim(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $mc_key, trim($encrypt), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv));
    $encode = base64_encode($passcrypt);
    return $encode;
}

// Decrypt Function
function mc_decrypt($decrypt, $mc_key) {
    $decoded = base64_decode($decrypt);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
    $decrypted = trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $mc_key, trim($decoded), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv));
    return $decrypted;
}
?>
```

if i call mc_encrypt('test', 'pass') all decrypts ok, but if i call  mc_encrypt('test=value', 'pass') i can't decrypt. why? and what must i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should tell us what happens, i.e. what code you call, what you expect, and what comes out. We cannot guess what "I can't decrypt" means.

I can give you one suggestion already though:

```
$passcrypt = trim(mcrypt_encrypt(
  MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $mc_key, trim($encrypt), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv));
```

**Don't mess with the input data [`trim($encrypt)`].** If the caller wants to trim the string, leave it to them to do it. Otherwise, if your input string has whitespace to trim, you will end up encrypting a *different* string than was passed in. That can only end in tears.

Comment: mc_decrypt return not decode string like ¹b\ˆ§Ä¢ˆLù óÃÄhMÙ8Ç†J